# Динамический вывод постов на wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Есть корпоративный сайт на котором есть страница новостного блога. Когда автор статей публикует записи, у пользователей они не отображаются пока они не обновят страницу. Заказчика это не устраивает, в пример он привел страницу РИА новостей (https://ria.ru/), там есть динамическая лента новостей (скрин прилагаю),

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

т.е. опубликовали запись - она сразу же появилась на глазах у пользователя, без обновлений страниц и прочего. Как сделать такое же на ВордПрессе?

Так же вот мой код для вывода постов:

```
<?php $my_posts = get_posts(array(
                'numberposts' => -1,
                'category_name' => 'news',
                'post_type' => 'post',

            ));

            foreach ($my_posts as $post) {
                $current_id = get_the_ID();                   
                setup_postdata($post);
                ?> >


                <a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>">
                <div class="news-item-container">

                <div class="news-item">
                    <div class="news-item-image">
                        <img class="news-image" src="<?php the_field('news_image'); ?>"
                             alt="Фотография новости">
                    </div>
                    <div class="news-description">
                        <h2 class="news-item-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                        <p class="news-item-text"><?php do_excerpt(strip_tags(get_the_content()), 20); ?></p>
                        <p class="news-item-date"><?php echo get_the_date('d.m.Y'); ?></p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                </div>
                
                </a>

                <?php
            }
            wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

У меня слабоват php и js, я совсем недавно в веб разработке, поэтому очень прошу, знающих людей, расписать чуть подробнее как это сделать. Ах да, чуть не забыл, я гуглил как только мог эту проблему, но выдает в основном ajax подгрузку постов при нажатии на кнопку "Загрузить еще". Это не то что нужно, пример как должно работать можно увидеть на сайте РИА новостей, в нижней части экрана лента новостей.

Comment: https://yandex.ru/search/?text=ajax+wordpress и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress+ajax

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin а подробнее можно? Я уже реализовал ajax подгрузку постов по кнопке, но это все равно не решает мою проблему, как именно мне задать вопрос с моей проблемой чтобы найти на него ответ?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin При публикации новой записи, я не увижу изменений на телефоне пока не обновлю страницу

Comment: С аяксом Вы разве что сможете реализовать AJAX Polling, но в зависимости от того как часто Вы решите опрашивать сервер, это может создать дополнительную нагрузку.

Comment: Для горячего обновления страницы при появлении новых постов надо открывать socket. Тогда сервер сможет динамически обновлять открытую в браузере страницу. В WordPress стандартных средств для работы с сокетами нет. Задача эта выходит за рамки начального уровня знаний php и js. Вам следует нанять специалиста для решения данной проблемы.

Comment: @KAGGDesign Жеско(( А может есть какой-то способ при публикации записи, чтобы кэш сбрасывался у пользователей? Суть в том что заказчики сайта жалуются что новые посты добавляются, но пока не пользователи не релогнут сайт, их не видно

Comment: @YONKOSHICHIBO  а при чем там кеш к обновлению страницы и выводу записей?

Comment: @Simon Я хз бро, вот и пытаюсь разобраться, сейчас я понимаю что мне либо с сокетами надо что то творить, либо может еще какой-то способ есть чтобы после публикации записи, у всех пользователей сбрасывался кэш автоматом, и они видели опубликованную запись...

Comment: Там сайт то небольшой на самом деле, просто и так бюджеты ограничены очень сильно, а если сейчас еще человека для реализации вебсокета искать.....

Comment: Сброс кеша, никоим образом не влияет на отображение записей в контексте Вашего вопроса. Вы точно уверены что Ваш вопрос именно про отображение новой записи без перезагрузки страницы? Потому что сброс кеша вообще не имеет к этому никакого отношения.

Comment: @Simon Может я и вправду неправильно описал проблему, попробую еще раз.

Сайт сделан на WP
Тема кастомная, делал сам
Если я публикую запись, то другой человек, если зайдет, при том что он уже заходил на сайт, к примеру вчера, не увидит новую запись, ему придется обновить страницу чтобы ее увидеть, я пытаюсь решить это

Comment: Вы используете какие-то плагины кеширования?

Comment: WP Fastest Cache

Comment: @YONKOSHICHIBO там же есть настройка `Очистить файлы кеша при публикации записи или страницы`, используйте ее.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен - перед скриптом который выводит посты из бд, нужно указать следующие строки:

```
<?php
                Header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
                Header("Pragma: no-cache"); // для протокола HTTP/1.1
                Header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . "GMT"); // дата и время генерации страницы
                header("Expires: " . date("r")); // дата и время время, когда страница будет считаться устаревшей
            ?>
```